# I can't show the time

Tags: python

I am trying to display the hours, since the current date, but I can't figure out how to do it.

this is the code i am using for it

```
from dateutil import parser




my_birthday= parser.parse("2022-11-05 15:16:18")

now = parser.parse("2022-11-07 2:45:20")

hours = now.hour - my_birthday.hour

print(f"{hours}")
```

It should show 4 hours

this is the url from which I get the date:
https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users?name=.iroke.
`"lastAccessTime": "2022-11-05T14:16:18.000+0000",`

Can someone help me with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It should show me 4 hours from the current date, but I can't do it

Comment: How is it...  4 hours?

Comment: would it be easier with the time module using the time.asctime() function?

Comment: 2 - 15 = -13. Where are you getting 4?